# Is it recommended to use TypeScript for writing the angular stuff for the Spartacus storefront?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am just exploring the Spartacus storefront.I was wondering if it is recommended to use TypeScript for writing the Angular stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's recommended. Angular team also recommends writing Angular app in TypeScript as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, without any doubt. Typescript provides lots of modern language features and the Angular team also recommends using TypeScript only.